# Customising a TableView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-2.2.1

I am trying to customise a TableView in my iPhone application.  I have found many tutorials that do this but they are all for version 3.0+.  I want to make my application as generic as possible so I can get it to work on as many iPhones/iTouches as possible.

Is it possible to create a customised TableView for 2.2.1 to 3?  I've found nothing and am beginning to think that it's not possible.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you should strongly consider whether it's really worth supporting pre-3.0 devices at this point. 3.0 has been preinstalled on all new devices for 9 months now, and I would wager that a large % of earlier devices with users who bother with applications have already upgraded. This number will only go up over time-- consider whether your time is better spent wrenching UITableView into shape for older devices or better spent adding better design and features for everyone else.

Comment: Exactly what kind of "customization" are you trying to do that you can't do with 2.x?

FWIW, a very, very small percentage of iPhone/iPod users are still on 2.x.  Is it really worthwhile to bend over backward to support people who are unwilling to upgrade?

Comment: I'm looking to do something like this: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: Also consider that the people who have not upgraded to 3.0 are probably also not downloading many (any?) apps. Does it make sense to write apps for those people?

Comment: @Kristopher - The example that I posted works on 2.2.1 through to 3.1.3 so I guess I should have done a bit more research before I posted my question.  But a big thanks to everyone :op)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the table in 2.2.1 AFAIK. In fact the tutorial you linked to above was written months before iPhone 3.0 was released!

But I have to agree with the comments above, supporting anything below 3.0 is probably not worth it. In particular, pre-3.0 you would initialize a UITableViewCell using initWithFrame, a method now deprecated. So if you decide to support 2.2.1 you risk your app not working on future releases of iPhone OS. With 4.0 around the corner this would not be a wise move.